# VS2012 plug-in that opens an app in a new VS tab

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to make VS2012 plug-in that opens an app in a new VS tab?
By VS tab I mean the same tab that opens when you click on an item in the Solution explorer.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Do you have the source code for the app, or is it an external application that you want to display within VS?

Comment: It's my app(WPF project). so it can be a source code or executable.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your app appear in a VS2012 document tab, you will have to write a Visual Studio extension that implements a document window. The Visual Studio [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668), its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb166441.aspx), and samples from the SDK and [MSDN code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=vsx&f%5B0%5D.Value=vsx&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=8) should help you get it implemented.